# How to properly save updates with MagicalRecord?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord, and I can't understand how to make it work stable and predictable.

When I need to update some entities, I retrieve them from DB, change them according to the logic, after then I send them into my “Saver” method:

```
- (void) saveEntities:(NSArray *)entities {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        for (Entity_class *entityElement in entities) {
           NSPredicate *entitySearchPredicate = [...] // Composing predicate
           Entity_class *foundEntity = [Entity_class MR_findFirstWithPredicate:entitySearchPredicate];
           foundEntity = entityElement;
        }
        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
        // contextDidSave always equals NO. Sometimes changes get saved, but sometimes they don't             
    }];
}
```

I've tried to save local context `[localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]` instead of the default one, but it never worked.

I'm struggling with these contexts for the second night, and just I've run out of the search query variants for Google. How to deal with context and save them properly?

Comment: I've just tried to save the context of the entity `[entityElement.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]` and it works. I still don't understand, why `saveWithBlock:` saves so unpredictably. And why in the world this method exists if all I need to do is to save the context of the entity?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few important notes to understand using CoreData:

1. You must save using the context the entity was created in.
   Meaning, if entities were created on a different thread they might be using a different context and sometimes that can cause faults when having multiple threads and a lot of saves-per-second.
2. The "saveWithBlock" method is for asynchronous saving, meaning it will save the context once its ready (usually its immediately), so if you try and check for changes right away and fetch the data, it might not have been saved yet.

It will help you to read more about the differences in core data between the different contexts - MainQueue and PrivateQueue.

Usually i'd use the given methods:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]
```

And

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]
```

You can also use the MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion: for asynchronous saving.

This way it saves the entire context without the need to select specific entities.

If you are new to it, you can also check [CoreDataStack](https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack)

Which is a more recent and up-to-date core data wrapper